# when running a simple python code it complains about main and spec being NONE

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and I found a very intesting library I need to play with which is only written in python

here us part of my code

```
from pkgutil import get_data

grammar = get_data(__name__, "thl.lark").decode("utf-8")
```

Now when I run it I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/thl/thl-jupyter-2020/thl/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    grammar = get_data(__name__, "thl.lark").decode("utf-8")
  File "/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/pkgutil.py", line 620, in get_data
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec(package)
  File "/xxx/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/importlib/util.py", line 114, in find_spec
    raise ValueError('{}.__spec__ is None'.format(name))
ValueError: __main__.__spec__ is None
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Why did you expect that to work?

Comment: I am trying to load some line on thl.lark with using get_data. I searched the web and usually __name__ is passed as a first param so I did the same

Comment: I cannot find out why get data is not loading thl.lark

Comment: What (and where) is `thl.lark`?

Comment: As I said this is part of a code for testing a library and I am new to python

Comment: it is in the same folder as test.py where I run my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run your script with `-m` flag provided it will work.
It means that your script will be executed as a module rather than a standalone script. I can assume that `pkgutil` requires a module to work.

```
python -m your_script.py
```

There's a [great blog post](https://realpython.com/lessons/executing-module/) about python modules and the difference between standalone scripts.

Comment: This might not raise an exception, but it's passing invalid arguments to `pkgutil.get_data`, and it only happens to work by fluke, due to a lack of argument validation. `pkgutil.get_data` is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data) to require a package name as the first argument. It's supposed to retrieve package contents.

Comment: Your great blog post is hidden behind a realpython paywall. Greatness is in doubt. As far as the difference between scripts and modules, the answer is not much other than by convention.  See [module v. script](https://www.pythonmorsels.com/topics/module-vs-script/).

Answer (score 0):

Start with solving line 6 and peel off parts you are unsure of, then adding them piece by piece.

Comment: line 6 is  grammar = get_data(__name__, "thl.lark").decode("utf-8") and I have no clue what is going on there

Comment: @Learner: Then why did you write that line?

Answer (score 0):

`pkgutil.get_data` is a function for retrieving resource files from packages.

Your `test.py` is not a package. It makes no sense to try to use `pkgutil.get_data` with it, as your file is an ordinary module, not a package, and it cannot contain any resource files.